# Can't find the formula to count columns with multiple criterias (OR and AND)

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

[image]

I'm trying to figure out the way to count the number of Draw for each team.
To count as a draw, a match had to be played (So no empty score value on both cells, and the team must appear in either column B or E, and the result must be "Draw")

Can anyone help me find the proper formulae? I already tried to use `COUNTIFS` but couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(FILTER({B2:B; E2:E}, {F2:F; F2:F}="Draw"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

and **F2** cell would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E<>"", 
 IF(C2:C=D2:D, "Draw", 
 IF(C2:C>D2:D, B2:B, 
 IF(C2:C<D2:D, E2:E, ))), ))
```

Comment: Is that normal that if there is no draw, a #N/A error comes up while evaluating FILTER function ? Thanks

Comment: yes, that's normal. to get rid off the error message wrap it all into `=IFERROR(QUERY(FILTER({B2:B; E2:E}, {F2:F; F2:F}="Draw"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''", 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Use Two COUNTIFS() and add them together:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"Real Madrid",F:F,"Draw")+COUNTIFS(E:E,"Real Madrid",F:F,"Draw")
```